# Is Javascript based validtion a security risk?

Tags: javascript, security, backbone.js, client-side-validation

I've noticed a big shift toward more and more client-side Javascript code these days. Packages like Backbone.js and others perform validation, access control and more. Is this causing security risks and if so what risks should we be aware of? Is Javascript based validation a security risk?

Comment: Javascript validation is in no way a security risk, the security risk is thinking clientside code does anything for security at all, and for that reason deciding not to do proper validation of all user inputted data on the serverside.

Comment: I can go into my developer tools and disable all security checks implemented in javascript.

Comment: No JavaScript framework does validation for *security* purposes, or even claims to do so; validation is only done to improve the user's experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a security risk if it isn't backed up with equivalent or stronger validation on the server side.

It can be very powerful as an ease-of-use feature to make the UX smoother, preventing tedious or jarring round-trips and page reloads, but you're quite right that you can't rely on it as a security feature.

Comment: So, don't you feel like you're now maintaining multiple sets of code to go the same thing? One client side & one server side.

Comment: @jjwdesign: with a bit of care you can ensure the same checks are done at both ends (eg with regex validation using a shared set of expressions).

Comment: Having to maintain two sets of validation seems like it goes against most OOP principles. I've recently started using a REST API with many jQuery .ajax calls. The validation is handled thru the REST API in the PHP/MySQL Model code. This way, I don't have to duplicate the validation in jQuery - only handle the response.

Answer (score 4):

Browser-based validation is a user convenience.

It has nothing to do with security, since it doesn't actually validate requests.

You still need to validate everything on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript validation in and of itself is not a risk.  Is can provide an additional layer of data validation/scrubbing.  What IS a risk is relying SOLELY upon client-side validation if your information is being passed to a server to process.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript should never be your security screening.  Javascript being client side, is vulnerable.  Javascript validation is used to ease user experience.

It is better to use server side scripting for security purposes.